# How to add data type any column while downloading excel file in react.js using xlsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xlsx

Here is my code to download the excel file

```
try {
    const response = await Axios(config);
    const outputFilename =
      "treasury_LOC_" + new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10) + ".xlsx";
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", outputFilename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  } catch (error) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can take reference from my code :

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

try {
  const response = await Axios(config);
  const outputFilename = "treasury_LOC_" + new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10) + ".xlsx";

  const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(response.data);

  // Define data types for specific columns
  worksheet["B1"].t = "n"; // Column B as number data type
  worksheet["C1"].t = "s"; // Column C as string data type

  const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Sheet1");

  const wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: "application/octet-stream" }));

  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", outputFilename);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
} catch (error) {}

function s2ab(s) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0; i != s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answer, without any explanation.

Comment: Tried but not changing the data type